# 2D Dataframe to a CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in below shape.

```
        M1  M2  M3
Cus1    11  1   2
Cus2    4   76  45
Cus3    4   8   6
```

I need to export this as csv to another file.And there after my intention is to use visualization software like (PowerBi,Cognos analytics) and make some graphs.
How to export the dataframe as it is into a csv in order to make the visualization

Comment: `df.to_csv('file.csv')`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
   df.to_csv('csv_filename.csv')
```

or,

```
df.to_csv('<path_to_csv_file>/csv_filename.csv')
```